# How do I change the reference column in Excel vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to change the reference column in the Excel vlookup from the first to any column. Here is my lookup table

```
Mon    PC Sales    Mobile Sales
Jan    800         700
Feb    500         750
Mar    600         860
```

My lookup values are PC Sales: 800 and Mobile Sales 860. Now I want to get their corresponding months, which is in the first column

Comment: *My lookup values are PC Sales: 800 and Mobile Sales 860* There is no answer for that, because there is no month where `PC Sales=800` **and** `Mobile Sales=860`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### VLOOKUP vs XLOOKUP

**Microsoft Office Support**

[VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)
... *Remember that **the lookup value should always be in the first column** in the range for VLOOKUP to work correctly. For example, if your lookup value is in cell C2 then your range should start with C.* ...

[XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)
... *Use the XLOOKUP function when you need to find things in a table or a range by row. For example, look up the price of an automotive part by the part number, or find an employee name based on their employee ID. With XLOOKUP, you can look in one column for a search term, and return a result from the same row in another column, **regardless of which side the return column is on**.*  ...
... *XLOOKUP is different from VLOOKUP in that **it uses separate lookup and return arrays**, where VLOOKUP uses a single table array followed by a column index number.* ...

**Conclusion**

- You cannot use `VLOOKUP` for the requested tasks.

**Either**

```
=XLOOKUP(800,$B:$B,$A:$A)
=XLOOKUP(860,$C:$C,$A:$A)
```

**Or**

If you don't have `XLOOKUP`, you can use [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) with [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a):

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(800,$B:$B,0))
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(860,$C:$C,0))
```